# JPA, struggling with a OneToMany relationship

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have two MySQL tables, the first...

cookbook

- id (int)
- user_id (int)
- recipe_id (int)
- created_at (datetime)

recipe

- id (int)
- title (varchar)
- etc etc

The purpose of the cookbook table is to keep track of recipe that users have added to their cookbook.

I've create a CookBook JPA entity, and I'm trying to pull the recipe into each cookbook row.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="cookbook")
public class CookBook {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Column(name="user_id")
    private int userId;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "recipe_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private List<Recipe> recipes;

    @Column(name="created_at", columnDefinition = "DATETIME")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createdAt;

    /* Getters and setters */
}
```

The issue is that no matter what I seem to try, I keep getting errors. With the above I get;

```
Unknown column 'recipes0_.recipe_id' in 'field list'
```

Which of course is correct as the recipes table doesn't contain that field. So I change the relationship in CookBook to;

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "recipe_id")
private List<Recipe> recipes;
```

When I do this my Spring Boot application won't run, it shows the error;

```
Unable to find column with logical name: recipe_id in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(cookbook) and its related supertables and secondary tables
```

Is someone able to indicate where I'm going wrong?

If it helps, I would see the final SQL looking something like this;

```
SELECT * FROM cookbook INNER JOIN recipe ON cookbook.recipe_id = recipe.id
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with "referencedColumnName" ? You specified that there is column in the related class (Recipe) called "id" which stores the FK to the CookBook ... and? If CookBook has a "recipe_id" then the relation is not a 1-N from CookBook. The "cookbook_id" should be in Recipe for that to be a 1-N, or you put the 1-N field in Recipe

Comment: I think what I was trying to do is make a link between cookbook.recipe_id and recipe.id. What I want to be able to do is run a query on the database to return all cookbook rows with a specific user Id, and also have the recipe it's linked to embedded into the results. Is there a way to do this without putting cookbook_id in the recipe entity, as that just 'feels' wrong to me as a recipe can belong to multiple cookbooks.

Comment: if you have a CookBook having recipe_id (i.e the FK from Cookbook to Recipe) then you should have the field in CookBook as "Recipe recipe" (N-1 or 1-1)

Comment: Your database tables are not normalized. If a cookbook should contain multiple recipes, the reference between them should be in recipe, not cookbook. If a recipe also can belong to multiple cookbooks, as you write above, then the relation is M:N and you will need a jointable. Fixing this will most assuredly make mapping a lot easier.

Comment: Ok thanks, I think I'll put the relationship in the user entity using the cookbook table as a join table.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else with this issue. The comments above are correct, I was doing it wrong.

In the end I resolved by problem by placing the relationship in the User entity so I could access each users cookbook recipes using;

```
user.getCookBookRecipes();
```

Here's the relationship I ended up using inside my User entity.

```
/* Cookbook */
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
    name="cookbook",
    joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
    inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="recipe_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
@JsonIgnore
private List<Recipe> cookbookRecipes;
```